# Is it possible to make an infinite directed acyclic graph with all vertices having a indegree of at least one

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is it possible to make an infinite directed acyclic graph with all vertices having a indegree of at least one. Since the graph is infinite and all vertices have a indgree of at least one, that would create cycles. Would that make a directed acyclic graph impossible to be infinite, and would always have to be finite to work?

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Z}$ as a vertex set of a directed graph, with $(m,m+1)$ an edge for every $m\in \mathbb{N}$? Is that not an example?

Comment: I wonder if you're saying "finite" when you mean "infinite" and vice versa? Because it's actually not possible to create a *finite* DAG where every vertex's indegree is at least one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the graph that has one vertex $v_i$ for each natural number $i \in \mathbb N$ and an edge $v_i \to v_j$ if and only if $i = j + 1$.

It is false that being infinite with all vertexes having in degree at least one implies the existence of a cycle.

Comment: Don't you mean “for each integer $i \in \mathbb{Z}$” instead of “for each natural number $i \in \mathbb{N}$”?

Comment: Arrows go down, so vertex $0$ doesn't have an arrow out, but everyone has an arrow in.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I should have read your answer more carefully. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Let $G=(V,E)$ where $V=\mathbb Z$, and $E=\{(a,b)\mid a+1 = b\}$.

This graph is obviously infinite, with in and out degree equal to $1$

Comment: You can extend this to $V=\mathbb R$ for an uncountable example

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make a directed acyclic graph with all vertices having a *countably infinite* indegree: start with a single vertex at Stage $0$; and at Stage $n+1$, for each vertex created in Stage $n$ you simply add countably infinite vertices that point to it.

This probably works for higher infinities as well, but there might be set-theoretic subtleties involved, and it's getting late here...